# How to reference System.Net.Sockets.Socket in PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, xamarin.uwp

I have been developing an app for Android, Ios and UWP.
Since I need a socket connection, I used DependenyService to access the "platform specific" code and started to implement my interface in all 3 projects.

The problem is that the implementation is exact the same in all 3 projects, because they all use `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`.
However I can't simply put the implementation code in my PCL and use it for all 3, because I can't reference `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` in my PCL. (doesn't exit there)

[This picture shows the targeting section of my PCL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWG5.png)

I think the problem is that my PCL targets ASP.NET Core 1.0, which doesn't contain an API for `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`.
However, I can't tell my PCL to stop target ASP.NET Core 1.0, because it gets targeted automatically.

So has anyone an idea how I can share code only between Android, Ios and UWP, or make my PCL only target them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the app should only support iOS, Android and UWP, you can switch to the PCL of the year 2016 and the future called .NET standard (>= 1.3).

In the properties of your PCL click `Target .NET Platform Standard` and select 1.3 or higher. If you don't have this option, you have to install/update some stuff. Requirements are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries

[image]

After you have done that, you are ready to use Sockets without using patterns like factory or dependency injection (which are the alternatives).

---

Or you use the Sockets plugin: https://www.nuget.org/packages/rda.SocketsForPCL

Comment: thank you very much! It took me some time, but now it works with .net standard.